# Vertically aligning a round list element hyperlink

Tags: css, list, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a header with 2 divs, the first one (floating to the left) is a simple horizontal unordered horizontal list, which is properly centered vertically (header has line-height the same as it's height and vertical-align: middle). The second div is floating to the right, and it also has a horizontal unordered list, however it has round (border-radius: 50%) hyperlinks and no text in them at all (they are going to be used as icons, with background-image).
While the first div is aligned properly no matter what is the size of header, the second one stays at the top.

My code:

```
#header
{
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
  color: black;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#header #icons
{
  float: right;
}

#header #icons ul
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header #icons ul li
{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

#header #icons ul li a
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #787878;
}
```

You can check the code & results here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mf6yg78f/
How can I vertically align the round list elements? I'd prefer to stay away from any flexboxes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Give `margin-top: 7px;` to `#header #icons`. There is no other option.

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

#wrapper
{
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

#header
{
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
  color: black;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#header #links
{
  float: left;
}

#header #links ul
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header #links ul li
{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
}

#header #links li:before
{
 content: " | ";
}

#header #links li:first-child:before
{
 content: none;
}

#header #links ul li a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}

#header #links ul li a:hover
{
  color: red;
}


#header #icons
{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
/* icons on the right side, should also be centered vertically */
#header #icons ul
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header #icons ul li
{
  list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

#header #icons ul li:first-child ~ li
{
 margin-right: 10px;
}

#header #icons ul li a
{
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 35px;
 height: 35px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #787878;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
  <div id="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="icons">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's actually 7.5px and that's not the only option. You can set: #header #icons ul {padding-top: 7.5px} to get the same result.

Comment: Yes I know that and I mean to say that without padding or margin there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use flex, then try to display items as table and table cell so that it will behave as table. `display:table-cell` will make the element behave as `<td>` and so you can add `vertical-align: middle` to it effectively

try changing the following style to:

```
/* icons on the right side, should also be centered vertically */
#header #icons ul
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  float: right;
}

#header #icons li
{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 35px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#header #icons ul li a
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #787878;
    margin: auto 0;
    float: right;
}
```